# Is there a way to make a function which returns True for certain type elements in a list and False otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to define a function which takes elements from a list and returns True for elements which contain integers first and charachters afterwards like `'243 abc'` and `'2-4 abc def'` and False for elements which only contain characters like `'abc def'` and `'abc 123'`

I'm new to programming and don't even know where to start. So after hours of trying to figure something out, I'm trying asking a question here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to look into _string slicing_ and [`isdigit`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `isdigit`:

```
>>> my_list = ["abc", "123 abc", "123"]
>>> [s[0].isdigit() for s in my_list]
[False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
my_list = ["abc", "123 abc", "123"]
new_list = [True if re.match("^[0-9]+.*[A-z]+", x) else False for x in my_list]
```

See more on regex [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and on list comprehnsion [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)